# ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api

In my Laravel-8 application, I have this api as json:

```
api/tracking/{TrackerID}?sub-key=jkkmkf
```

which looks like:

api/tracking/19SB22?sub-key=jkkmkf

It is a GET request

When I tried to consume it as shown below, I got this error:

> ErrorException
> Undefined offset: 0

and it points to this line:

> $current = $json[0];

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

```
public function index() {
    $request = Request::create('/api/tracking', 'GET');
    $response = Route::dispatch($request);
    $information = $response->content();
    $json = json_decode($information, true);
    $current = $json[0];
    $geo = explode(',', $json[0]['current_asset_position_coord']);
    return view('welcome', [
        'current' => $current,
        'json' => $json,
        'geo' => $geo
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the array (`$json`) doensn't contains value with 0 key, your `json_decode` returns you an empty array.

To make requests to external API's please have a look at [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/)

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;


$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('https://example.com/api/tracking/19SB22', ['sub-key' => 'jkkmkf']);
echo $res->getStatusCode(); // 200
$json = $res->getBody()->getContents();
```

Comment: How do I apply  api/tracking/{TrackerID}?sub-key=jkkmkf or  api/tracking/19SB22?sub-key=jkkmkf   in $request = Request::create('/api/tracking', 'GET');